# How to make the function to return the query result?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services

This work fine:

```
var test = myFunc(2); // 4
function myFunc(id){
    return id*2
}
```

But this code doesn't work:

```
var test = myFunc(2); // {}
function myFunc(id) {
   return  myService.getById(id).then(function (result) {
       console.log(result[0].name); // John
       return result[0].name;
   });
}
```

Could you help me to fix my second example, please?

Comment: You're defining a variable with the name `test` and a function with the name `test`. I have no idea what this is supposed to do.

Comment: In your second snippet, your function returns a promise for the name "John". That's as good as it gets, because the name will only be available asynchronously. It does not need a fix. What is your problem with this, what do you considered broken?